# LESS body height calculation

Tags: css, less

I am using `100vh` for my body content, but how can I make it so it takes away the height of my navbar?

Like

```
100vh - 50px
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try searching online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do so in LESS with the following

```
calc(~"100vh - 50px");
```

If you're happy with just a css solution, here is an example

```
calc(100vh - 50px);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/m4zobc1c/)

Comment: I see, I didn't know I had to use calc, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the calc() css function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
Doesn't work in all browsers.   vh/vw/vmin support in this might be even smaller.

except in LESS you have to escape it, to prevent it being calculated by the compiler, like so:

```
height: calc(~'100vh - 50px');
```